# List of choices for Macintosh/device management solutions?

Tags: devices

We are in a small company of about 8 people and need to start getting serious about the management of our Mac computers.  We are going to stick with Mac only to make things easier/consistent.  I read about JAMF and rippling.com and will be talking to them.  I have a few questions.

Are there other solutions as well I should explore?
Does anyone know of any tradeoffs in those solutions?
Below in my list of things I am thinking about, what am I missing or not thinking about and should be?

The list of things I am thinking about is

1. How to protect the computers from virus
2. How to remotely patch computers
3. How to lock down BYOD Mac computers as well (my guess here is make it just like another company computer)
4. Check on state of all computers
5. What specs can I be compliant with using solution X (referencing spec compliance for customer is a very nice thing)

BONUS: How to protect data and possibly wipe based on timer if user not logged in within a certain amount of time

I hope this is the right forum.  I don't see tags on device management which falls in the real of IT administration.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: FYI: It's just Mac. MAC is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address.

Comment: Or a makeup company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a common set of requirements but I think you'll be challenged to find everything you've specified in one solution, since A/V and compliance spec may be additional cost or out of scope.

Given your size, Jamf NOW seems to be a perfect set but as you've said you're already looking into that, I'd recommend evaluating JumpCloud if you're interested in Scale and more refined management. Jamf and JAMF Now are great but if you believe you'll find a good amount of features at an easier to deploy rate https://jumpcloud.com/product/ .

If you are looking to put on paper that you have MDM for your macs, I would evaluate JAMF NOW and work on advanced security features (compliance/AV) with a different product.